# Google Isn't Showing Data in my Paid Search Traffic Report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, google-analytics-api

I've just recently noticed that Google isn't showing any data for my "Paid Search Traffic." I know for a fact that I should have data, since I've spent money on campaigns.

There's also no data under "Campaigns."

Is there something I need to add to my tracking code? Apparently it's in the public beta stage, which Google didn't inform me... thus, I don't know what to expect really.

**Tracking code:**

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', 'caseykidd.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you mean Google AdWords campaigns, you should [connect your AdWords account to your Google Analytics account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en).

You don't need to change the tracking code, whether it's Universal Analytics or the older version.

Comment: The two are connected, and I can see Analytics in my Adwords account.

Comment: Is the auto-tagging turned on? How about redirects? If there's immediately a redirect after a user lands from an ad, you lose all campaign info.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to ensure that your declared domain matches the actual domain visitors landing on. If you are sending visitors to a subdomain they will come through as direct once they click through to your root domain. If using subdomains need to declare as '.caseykidd.com'